# Quantum algorithm circuit with Quantikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuits, quantikz

I'm trying with no results to use latex for drawing the famous “Deutsch algorithm”:[image].

For this use case, I've tried like every latex package for quantum circuits. The one with which I was able to obtain acceptable results is quantikz.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quantikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{quantikz}
\lstick{$\ket{0}$} & \gate{H} &
    \gate[wires=2][1.7cm]{U}
        \gateinput[1]{$x$} 
        \gateoutput[wires=1]{$x$} & \gate{H}\\
            &\gateinput{$y$}
            \gateoutput{$y\oplus f(x)$}&\qw\\
\lstick{$\ket{1}$} & \gate{H} 
\end{quantikz}

\end{document}
```

Resulting in:

[image]

The main problem is that I cannot find a way to insert the second qubit into the y gate of U. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know the `quantikz` package. I don't know nothing about quantum computation come to that. However, your picture is easy to draw in plain Ti*k*Z. I'm sure you'll have other solutions with `quantikz` or another related package. Meanwhile I hope this example can be helpful.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=-1cm,scale=1.5]
\foreach\i in {0,1}
  \draw (5,\i) -- (0,\i) node[left] {$\lvert\i\rangle$};
\foreach\i/\j in {1/0,1/1,4/0}
  \draw (\i,\j) node[draw,fill=white] {$H$};
\draw[fill=white] (1.75,-0.25) rectangle node {$U_f$} (3.25,1.25);
\foreach[count=\j from=0]\i in {0.5,1.5,3.5,4.5}
  \draw[<-] (\i,1.5) -- (\i,2) node[below] {$\lvert\psi_\j\rangle$};
\node[right] at (1.75,0) {$x$};
\node[left]  at (3.25,0) {$x$};
\node[right] at (1.75,1) {\strut$y$};
\node[left]  at (3.25,1) {\strut$y\oplus f(x)$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For the record this is the `quantikz` code.

[image: b]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quantikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{quantikz}
    \lstick{$\ket{0}$}  &\gate{H}   &\gate[wires=2][1.7cm]{U_f}\gateinput[1]{$x$}\gateoutput[1]{$x$}&\gate{H}   &\qw\\
    \lstick{$\ket{1}$}  &\gate{H}   &\qw\gateinput{$y$}\gateoutput{$y\oplus f(x)$}                  &\qw        &\qw\\  
\end{quantikz}

\end{document}
```

And with the added labels.

[image: c]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quantikz}   
\begin{document}

\begin{quantikz}
    \lstick{$\ket{0}$}  &\gate{H}   &\gate[wires=2][1.7cm]{U_f}\gateinput[1]{$x$}   \gateoutput[1]{$x$} & \gate{H}  &\qw\\
    \lstick{$\ket{1}$}  &\gate{H}   &\qw\gateinput{$y$}\gateoutput{$y\oplus f(x)$}                  &\qw & \qw\\ 
\end{quantikz} \\[-4ex]
\hspace*{1.0cm}\begin{tikzpicture}[y=-1cm]   
    \draw[<-] (2.7,2.5) -- (2.7,3) node[below] {$\lvert\psi_0\rangle$};  
    \draw[<-] (3.8,2.5) -- (3.8,3) node[below] {$\lvert\psi_1\rangle$};     
    \draw[<-] (6.1,2.5) -- (6.1,3) node[below] {$\lvert\psi_2\rangle$};  
    \draw[<-] (7.1,2.5) -- (7.1,3) node[below] {$\lvert\psi_3\rangle$};                 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```